# Easiest way to transfer create this map (html5 canvas/javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dictionary

I'll explain with an example.

I have painted a simple map in photoshop.
I want to break into tiles this map and record every tile to the database. (x:1 y:1 = green, x:1 y:2 = green, x:1 y:2 = blue etc.)

This is my tile: [image]

My map is 100x110 tile. Just like that:  [image]

And my simple photoshop map is that: 
[image]

ıs there any method to import my photoshop map to my database tile by tile?
for example; it defines the greens as grass, blues as water and yellows as sand.

than it record it to my database automatically as "x:1 y:1 grass, x:2 y:1 grass, x:3 y:1 water etc"

or do I have to make it tile by tile with my hand?
do I have to click first tile and define it as water, click second and define it as grass bla bla bla?

is there anyway to make it so easier than making it one by one?

Comment: You should create a tool to create maps for your game. Don't use photoshop for this.

Comment: BTW, the geometry of the tile is going to a real problem. If it was square or rectangular it wouldn't be so much of a problem; you could save the image to canvas then use a function to iterate over the square tiles, identify the colour, and produce an array. Not so much with a hexagon.

Comment: What color would the tile become if the hexagon on the photoshop map contains part-green, part-lightBlue and part-darkBlue? For example, let's declare that the one pixel at dead-center of your hexagon determines the color, then your mapping from photoshop to hexagons is very easy.  It would also result in a very "pixelated" hexagon representation of the original photoshop map.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to write a program which would scan your image to a particular scale and then output the map indexes and tile types to the database, however, I would recommend that you have a look at an open source map editing tool called Tiled. This allows you to design your map visually and then export it to a number of formats.

http://www.mapeditor.org/